# Chartboost shows video when showInterstitial() is called

Tags: chartboost

I am using the latest version of Chartboost ANE with my Starling based game. I call

```
Chartboost.getInstance().showInterstitial(location);
```

on the home screen. Chartboost starts playing a video ad. Shouldn't it show a regular static interstitial ad instead? Where does this video come from?

Comment: Im having the same issue in reverse. (trying to show video and I get Interstitial ad's)  Naut's answer doesn't solve the problem.  Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the campaigns that your app is using for interstitials have their type set to "static interstitial"

To check, open your developer dashboard and select the app, then select "Campaigns", then select "Publishing". Under "Ad Type", the campaign should say "static".

(Also, is you app currently in test mode? This is just speculation, but I recall having seen a video ad sneak through while testing.)